# To find the Modulus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, fractions, absolute-value

I was given the following expression ,

$|\frac{(3+i)(2-i)}{(1+i)}|$ ,

and was asked to find its value

This is how I proceeded ,

On solving the numerator , the given expression transforms to 
$|\frac{7-i}{1+i}|$
Then I took the conjugate of the denominator and finally got the expression

$\frac{8-8i}{2}$

$= 4|(1-i)|$

Now according to me it’s modulus should be $4\sqrt{2}$ however the correct answer is $5$ . Could you please correct me where I am mistaken ? And please suggest a method to solve this. Thank you .

Comment: $$\left|\dfrac{ab}c\right|=\dfrac{|a||b|}{|c|}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$\left|\frac{(3+i)(2-i)}{(1+i)}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{10}\cdot\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt2}=5.$$

Answer (score 3):

$(7-i)(1-i) \ne 8-8i$ but $(7-i)(1-i) = 6-8i$. So $\big|\frac{6-8i}{2} \big| = 5$.

Easier way to evaluate is seperating the absolute value as:
$$\bigg|\frac{(3+i)(2-i)}{(1+i)}\bigg| = \frac{|3+i|
|2-i|}{|1+i|} = \frac{\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}} = 5$$

Comment: Thank you !! Just realized that I made a silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

note that $$\frac{(3+i)(2-i)}{1+i}=3-4i$$